# way to alert me the developer of an error in my iPhone app

Tags: objective-c

I have this iPhone that loads a different part of a website based on what button you click. AKA it links to a sport website and the first page contains all the sports the site offers as buttons. I have code to check if the website is valid/up and if it’s not to display an error message. Is there a way in the code to like alert me somehow, like an email maybe, of such an error such as an invalid url? Like for example if the website removes a sport w/o my knowledge and a user goes to open the link and receives that error, can the app send an email to me (not from the users account, but like a background account maybe) that can alert me of such an error. Or maybe somehow have me access then NSLog of an error that i give?

Answer (score 1):

There is something called TestFlight App that I use to log errors like that. You can read up on it here

http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829571-does-the-sdk-support-production-builds-

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [Parse](https://www.parse.com/) integrated app.
Alternatively, if you have access to a web server you could create a simple script that you could `POST` to in the app to let you know of any problems.

Answer (score -2):

Since the user has connectivity on the internet, try creating a web service and use POST with some meaningful data.

If you don't develop server side as well find a web server that offers such a service.